# Bad real number

Tags: fortran

```
program mult1
implicit none
real::x,s,c,t
write(*,*)'Enter value for angle'
Read(*,*) x
s=sin(x)
write(*,*)'s=',s
stop
end program mult1
```

My program does not work it says

```
Fortran runtime error: Bad real number at (1)
```

Comment: What is the input for this program?

Comment: compile as fortran 90 code with gfortran shows no problem at all. please clarify your input, platform or how it was compiled and tested to help others repeat your issue.

Comment: A message like that usually comes up if you type in characters when Fortran is, of course, expecting a valid real number.

Comment: What is (1) pointing at (in the line above)? And are you by any chance using a decimal seperator other than the system one (e.g. ',' instead of '.')?